# Swift 3 URLSession sending empty request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I can't get the URLSession to send anything in the body of a POST request.

Here is my code:

```
// Set up the request
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL + url)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values,
                                                  options: .prettyPrinted)
request.httpBody = jsonData
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
    if let err = err {
        print(err)
    }
    else {
        let jsondata = data!
        do {
            let sessionData =
                        try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsondata, options: .mutableLeaves)
                            as? Dictionary<String, String>
            callback.taskComplete(response: sessionData, task: task)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

The server receives the request, but the body is empty and the content type header is null. I can't use the default session because I'm developing with self-signed certificates, so I need my class to be a URLSession delegate.

I'm using Swift 3, XCode 8, and iOS 10. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have data in `jsonData` property ?

Comment: debug your project at jsondata or print in and check log

Comment: All looks good, the only thing can be having some problems is your `httpBody`.

Comment: request.HTTPBody = jsonData replace your line .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya - `HTTPBody` is Swift 2.3. In Swift 3, it's `httpBody`.

Comment: SteveB - Sometimes it's useful to use a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org). That way you can see what's getting sent and received, and unambiguously identify the source of the issue (e.g. if the request looks good in Charles/Wireshark, then the problem is likely in the server code or however you confirmed the empty response and no content-type header; if the request in Charles/Wireshark doesn't look good, then of course the problem is in the client code creating the request).

Comment: @Rob but i never face that kind of problem in my project . and ya he has a problem with nill data in jsonData

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya - Then you must be using Swift 2.3 in your project. But he was explicit that he was using Swift 3, and that uses `httpBody`. Besides, if that were the problem, he'd be getting a compile-time error, not some curious run-time behavior. (By the way, I've rejected your edit in which you tried to change his code.)

Comment: @Rob ok did you check my one problem that i face during install pod file in my project

Comment: I had previously added some print lines to check jsonData. It has a proper JSON string. As well, that wouldn't explain why the content-type header field is null when it gets to the server.

Comment: @Rob The request is going over TLS, so raw packet inspection isn't an option.

Comment: TLS, itself, isn't generally a problem with Charles' proxy capabilities, but perhaps your self-signing cert could be a barrier.

Comment: I haven't ever used charles. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was a combination of errors. If the URL doesn't have the trailing "/", Jetty sends a 302 redirect to the same URL with the slash appended. The iOS client does the redirect with a "GET," so there is nothing in the body. When I add the trailing "/", the request works fine.

I hope this answer will help someone doing iOS development. I searched Google for hours before I posted this question. I finally found the answer in a post about the Apache Java HttpClient. It has the same behavior.

Thank you for all the responses.

Comment: There is something weird going on with URLSessions and trailing slashes... In my case, iOS was stripping off the `Authorization` header if I didn't have a trailing slash on the API call. h/t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885587/nsurlconnection-authorization-header-not-working